# Android java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: method was not called

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I'm writing tests with mockito, trying to check if a method was called, but I always get this error:

**java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: method was not called**

This is the method call on my fragment:

```
private val tracker: PJAccountTracker by inject()

btnBack.setOnClickListener {
   tracker.tagAction(ACTION_DATA_VALIDATION_BACK, PAGE_DATA_VALIDATION)
   popBackStack()
}
```

And this is the test I'm doing:

```
private val tracker = mockk<PJAccountTracker>(relaxed = true)

fun verifyBackButtonAction() {
   verify(exactly = 1) {
        tracker.tagAction(ACTION_DATA_VALIDATION_BACK, PAGE_DATA_VALIDATION)
   }
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, since the method is called when clicking on the button... if anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it!

By the way, I'm using Koin for dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Replace

private val tracker = mockk(relaxed = true)

With

private val tracker: PJAccountTracker by inject()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).